# Input and Output files

Tags: c++

I am attempting to create a new input text file and read the contents of it and write to my output file. Thing is I tried so many things, Can someone explain what I should do with my code. Anything I can change.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int main()
 {
    string fileName,fileName2,text;
    cout << "Please enter file name fo input: ";
    getline(cin ,fileName);
    cout << "Please enter file name for output: ";
    getline(cin, fileName2);
    ofstream output(fileName2,ios_base::app);
    std::fstream inFile;
    inFile.open(fileName, std::fstream::in | std::fstream::out | std::fstream::trunc);
    getline(inFile, text);
    while(inFile)
    {
        inFile >> text;
    }
    output << text;
    output.close();
    inFile.close();
    return 0;
 }
```

Comment: What you should do is use your debugger to step through your code, one line at a time, see how it logically executes each instruction, and what are the values of all the variables at each step of the way. Once you do that, the obvious bug in the shown code should be quite apparent. Knowing how to use a debugger is a required skill for every C++ developer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- you should clean up input buffer because getline doesn't flush it for you.

"inFile.open(fileName, std::fstream::in | std::fstream::out | std::fstream::trunc);"

remove "| std::fstream::out | std::fstream::trunc" because this flag clear the content of input file while opening it.

- another thing why you try to use input stream inFile as output stream for another file (output file)??
- so remove flags: ios::trunc and ios::out because you only want to open first file for reading.

your program should look like:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int main()
 {
    string fileName, fileName2, text;

    cout << "Please enter file name fo input: ";
    getline(cin ,fileName);
    cin.ignore(1, '\n');

    cout << "Please enter file name for output: ";
    getline(cin, fileName2);
    cin.ignore(1, '\n');

    ofstream output(fileName2.c_str(), ios_base::app);

    std::fstream inFile;
    inFile.open(fileName.c_str(), std::ios::in);

    if(!inFile)
        cout << "Failed to open input file!" << endl;
    while(getline(inFile, text) )
    {
        output << text;
    }


    output.close();
    inFile.close();
    return 0;
 }
```

Comment: Hmm do you know why I get the failed to open input file message when i Run the program

Comment: what output you got? do you have an input file? what message you got?

Comment: I entered the name for the input file and output file. And then my output said failed to open file

Comment: But I I also got a file on my debug folder of the text underneath the input file name

Comment: have you entered the full name of the file (name + extension)? eg: in my example: I enter "data.txt". and be sure that this file is in the current directory.

Comment: Well I was wanting to create a new file using the file name given by user input, is that what you did?

Comment: @Athuro: create a file "data.txt" by notepad put some code inside it. move this file to your c++ root directory. when running the program it asks you about the input file so enter data.txt then it asks you for output file name so enter for example test.txt. everything surely will work fine

Comment: For the output file would I need to create that before I run the program?

Comment: @Arhuro yes!!! and finally you get it.

Comment: Hey  I did what you said. It worked perfectly! Thank You

Comment: I'm sorry I have been bugging you, i've been trying so hard to get a grasp of coding but i'll get there

Comment: @Arhuro: ok never mind. sounds good getting worked for you. we collaborate here.